# Saving high score Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, datastore

Guys I have developed a small game and I want to save high score on same screen.

I thought it's easy to save the integer but the problem is that I have no idea where to start can anyone guide me if you want I can give you my code

Comment: you can save your score in `SharedPrefrence`

Comment: do you mean save the integer between page loads? why is this tagged javascript and Android? Android runs java

Comment: @AJay if you can guide me i am very thank full to you

Comment: Please pick one of the bazillion tutorials on the subject you can easily google for.

Answer (score 2):

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

to save data

```
Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putInt("key", your score goes here);
editor.commit();
```

and than to retrive your score back

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);    


int highScore = sharedpreferences.getInt("key" , defaultValue);
```

There you go

Comment: If you have time can you show me somewhere and then that i copy and past please

Comment: you just have to put this lines of code whenever you want to save your score. Show me your code and tell me from where you want to save score.

Comment: where you wanted to shave just use my code above. you should try and than tell me instead of looking for copy paste code

Comment: I tried sire many errors are coming i dont have idea where to put these code and how so thats why i want your help i tried many time but i failed if you can please do for me if you want

Comment: please can you help me?

Comment: dear I helped you out. Now what you want me to do. you just have to replace two variables only. now please mark this as accepted answer.